# Get values at specific time intervals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet containing test data. The data are temperature readings at fairly regular intervals. I say "fairly" because the readings are usually at 10 second intervals, but occasionally the test hardware skips a reading or two.
For the purposes of this exercise we can ignore the missing data.

The first reading is at 09:00:00 on 12th May 2016 and the last reading is at 09:10:10 on 20th May 2016. File available to download here:
http://mbf.me/3XkRR0

I would like to find the average temperature at each hour interval.
It would be great if these average values could be inserted in a new column (for example column D).

For example, in cell B361, the time is 09:59:50. The next cell B362 would signify the next hour time segment, so in cell D361 I would like to see the average of the temperature readings from cell C2 to C361 inclusive. Then at the next hour interval cell D718 would show the average of the temperature readings from cell C362 to C718 inclusive.
D1078 would average the cells C719 to C1078, and so on.

Although I don't have any VBA workings to show for myself here, I have been trying various things in excel (for example autofill series formulas) but to no avail.  To be honest I don't think I can get my head around the way Excel deals with times to figure this out, let alone translate that into code using my limited VBA skills. I think the fact that the time intervals aren't truly consistent, and the data spans several days, is making this difficult for me to solve.

This is the first time I've posted a question, so apologies if I have disobeyed any rules (I managed to write my debut VBA Excel code without posting a question, although I did consult stackoverflow many times during that process!)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what you asked for, but is another approach to consider:

## Pivot Table

In your example file, the `Time` column is really *Date/Time* formatted to show just the time.

So you could

- Insert Pivot Table
- Drag Time to the Rows Area
- Drag Temp to the Values Area
- Edit the Temp to show `Average` (instead of the default `Sum`) and format the number as you wish (I used a single decimal)
- Right click on a row item in the Pivot Table and select to group by Hours and Days (or just by Hours, if you want)
- Add a little formatting

Pivot grouped by hours & days:

[image]

Pivot grouped just by hours:

[image]

Comment: This is a brilliant alternative approach. Although I didn't mention it in my question, the next task for me is to create a chart from the averaged data.  Thanks for suggesting the pivot approach, because I learnt a lot from following your steps, and in addition I noticed I could create a pivot chart which took me right where I wanted to go.  No VBA needed afer all...

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the top of column D and fill down.

```
=if(hour(b2)<>hour(b2+time(0, 0, 10)), averageifs(c:c, b:b, ">="&int(b2)+time(hour(b2), 0, 0), b:b, "<="&int(b2)+time(hour(b2), 59, 59)), "")
```

Comment: This is a neat way to isolate the values I needed from the original data. Your formula skills are strong!